# Using react-table, accessing data nested in object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I'm creating a table using react-table and Typescript. Now I'm having some difficulty in accessing the data I get returned from my API. I'm just using Google Books API. Now I've created a table component, which receives some data which is an array with objects. Now these objects contain nested data which I have defined in a Books interface, in which I only include the data I need from the API response.

Below is my Book interface:

```
export interface Book {
  id: number;
  isbn: {
    volumeInfo: {
      industryIdentifiers: {
        type: string;
        identifier: string;
      }[];
    };
  };
  title: {
    volumeInfo: {
      title: string;
    };
  };
  authors: {
    volumeInfo: {
      authors: string[];
    };
  };
  publishedDate: {
    volumeInfo: {
      publishedDate: string[];
    };
  };
}
```

I've created an array where I've defined my columns using documentation from react-table:

```
import { Book } from "./home.types";

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<Book>();

const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor("id", {
    header: () => "ID",
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("isbn", {
    header: () => "ISBN",
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("title", {
    header: () => "Title",
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("authors", {
    header: () => "Authors",
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor("publishedDate", {
    header: () => "Date of publication",
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  }),
];
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the data is being loaded in the table, but all other data isn't, and I don't really see why. I'm pointing to the locations of the data in the response I'm feeding my table.

I think I'm just not clearly seeing it, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying you cannot access the values in the nested objects (i.e you want to display the *value* of `title.volumeInfo.title`), you would do something like the below. From your example, you are simply providing React Table with an object and it won't know how you want to display it.

```
const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor("title.volumeInfo.title", {
    header: () => "Title",
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  })
 // other columns here...
];
```

Take this with a grain of salt though, I don't use the `columnHelper` approach and just use the static column configuration. Based on what you provided, you can probably use it as well. Makes it a lot more maintainable/readable, and it avoids all of the useless callbacks.

```
const columns = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      header: 'Title',
      accessorKey: 'title.volumneInfo.title'
    },
    // other columns here...
  ],
  [] // put any updater dependencies in the second array if you need
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this method if you like. Though the headline says v7.I've answered for v8

[Rendering React Table [v7] results in [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163623/rendering-react-table-v7-results-in-object-object/75635513#75635513)